# set /p or alternative on MS-DOS (Windows ME)

Tags: dos

How can I set a variable to a user's input on Windows ME?

`SET /P` doesn't work on Windows Millennium Edition (I know, i am using it for a project...), so I need an alternative command that sets a variable to the users input (it has to be multi character). Or, if someone knows how to get `set /p` on Windows ME that would be good.

Comment: did you search online before posting your issue??

Comment: Yes, i did, I couldn't find anything that worked.

Comment: maybe http://krypted.com/windows-server/resolve-530-5-7-1-client-was-not-authenticated-error-in-exchange-2010-2012/  OR https://support.sonicwall.com/sonicwall-email-security/kb/184845

Comment: That is nothing to do with set /p var=.....

Comment: The linked question isn't a duplicate. This question is about obtaining the user's input, the other question is about obtaining the output of a program.